# SSL Certificates Popup in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have installed SSL on node server.  I have made changes in app.js too.

Now when i am trying to run my website

example.com

I am getting Popup like this

[image]

Why i am getting this popup?

Is certificates doesn't installed correctly?

Thanks

Comment: The browser is asking you if you wish to authenticate yourself to the server using a certificate. Clearly you have a certificate and a public/private key pair attached to your local account, or it wouldn't be asking you. 

Simply click cancel if this is not intended.

Use the Windows Certificate Manager to check what certificate it is.

Comment: Ben , Can you tell how to check i have a certificate and a public and private key pairs attached to my local account

Comment: in windows 10, hit start then type "certificates"

Answer (score 2):

The browser is asking you if you wish to authenticate yourself to the server using a certificate.

Clearly you have a certificate and a public/private key pair attached to your local account, or it wouldn't be asking you.

Simply click cancel if this is not intended.

Use the Windows Certificate Manager to check what certificate it is. In all likelihood you have installed the server certificate as a personal certificate on your account.

Comment: Ben , Can you tell how to check i have a certificate and a public and private key pairs attached to my local account